# Selecting non-contiguous regions in Godot tilemap editor for atlas creation

Tags: tile, godot

I'm trying to create an atlas of collideable objects in Godot's tilemap editor.  My understanding is that, to select a region of tiles to make part of the atlas, you have to mouse select (I tried clicking a cell and holding `Shift` but it doesn't select multiple cells).  The issue is that I can't seem select a non-square region.

[image: Fantasy tilemap]

I also tried selecting cells one at a time, adding the collision area, and then picking a new cell, and what I end up seeing is my `range` of cells shift over to the new area.  Do I need to re-create my tilemap source to just have contiguous regions, or is there some Godot functionality I'm missing here?  FWIW, I was following [this tutorial](https://www.davidepesce.com/2019/10/18/godot-tutorial-7-using-tile-maps-to-create-game-map/) to get up and running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The region has to be a rectangle. You may want to break it up into multiple atlases plus a New Single Tile for the one at the top by itself.

```
Single Tile
Atlas 8x1
Atlas 2x1
Atlas 2x1
```

When you go to paint, selecting any of the atlases will show you the tiles inside.